# How attributes from different objects can refer to each other

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how certain object attributes can refer to attributes of another object. For example, I have an object with name "A" and children ["B", "C"]. I also have the child B with name "B" and children ["D", "E"]. Now I want these to have a parent attribute. Is there a way for B and C to automatically know their parent attribute is A... and for D and E to know it's B.  See below:

```
class FamilyTree:
    def __init__(self, name, children, parent):
        self.name = name 
        self.child = child
```

I don't want to next do:

```
self.parent = parent
```

I want B to know its parent attribute is A.

Comment: No; you have to set the `parent` attribute explicitly.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

The parent has to be set explicitly somewhere. If you don't want to set it in the child, you can do this:

```
class FamilyTree:
    def __init__(self, name, children):
        self.name = name 
        self.children = children
        for child in children:
            child.parent = self
```

Comment: Sorry, it may because I am new to this but when I tried to implement the above I got:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'parent'. Any advice?

Comment: This code will work if: 1) `children` is an array of instances instead of strings and 2) those instances are already declared. E.g.,: `son = FamilyTree('Son', []); dad = FamilyTree('Dad', [son])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but, at first, you should keep track of instances and create additional storage, at second, your child name should be unique (if both 'Dad_1' and 'Dad_2' have son named 'John', how would you know whose 'John' it is). And, of course, instance of parent should exist before you creating instance of son.

```
class FamilyTree(object):
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, name, children=None):
        self.name = name 
        self.child = children
        for inst in FamilyTree.instances: # Dad finder
            if inst.child:
                if self.name in inst.child:
                    self.parent = inst.name
        FamilyTree.instances.append(self) # Add instance to storage

dad = FamilyTree('Dad', ['Son', 'Daughter'])
son = FamilyTree('Son', ['Son_of_Son', 'Daughter_of_Son'])
son.parent

Out[297]: 'Dad'
```

There can be other solutions using decorators or MetaCalsses. That is the most obvious one.